# Problema com conexão banco firebird hibernate

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, servlet

Tenho uma aplicação em java que disponibiliza serviços rest com servlets e hibernate, que em primeiro momento funciona perfeitamente. Posso fazer milhares de requisições a diversos serviços que recuperam informações na base firebird que ela responde muito bem...
Mas algumas vezes o firebird trava ou simplesmente é reiniciado, e então minha aplicação *ficava* travava com problemas de comunicação mesmo quando o banco firebird voltava a funcionar. Então era necessário reiniciar minha aplicação para voltar ao normal.

Resolvi este problema de ré-conexão, adicionando os comandas abaixo no arquivo hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">120</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">600</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1</property>
```

Depois de 120 segundos que o bando parado voltava a funcionar, a aplicação também reiniciava a conexão, e permitia fazer novas requisições...

Então me deparei com um outro problema.

**Depois de a aplicação voltar a funcionar, a mesma fica instável. Ela passa a retornar erros de conexão sincronizado de acordo com as quantidade de requisições: hora a cada três requisições com sucesso uma é retornada o erro (Sempre nessa ordem); e se fizer um novo teste, reiniciando a aplicação, este cronograma pode mudar, como a cada 5 requisição uma falha...**

Esse erro ***sincronizado*** me parece um sintoma de um erro que me desarmou...

Todo meu código de configuração do hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/D:/automacao/projetos/DB/DB.FDB</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">USER</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">*******</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">1</property>
<!--Configurações adicionais -->
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="connection.relaxAutoCommit">true</property>
<property name="connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">on_close</property>
<!-- Usando as configurações do C3PO para pool de conexões -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">120</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">600</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1</property>
```

Peço a ajuda de alguém para tentar resolver este problema.

**Infelizmente não consegui uma solução, acredito que possa ser um erro no driver de conexão do firebird.
Mas consegui contornar criando um serviço do Windows que testa a aplicação de tempos em tempos e reinicia o apache tomcat se houver algum erro.**

Answer (score -1):

Segundo a documentação do Hibernate é [altamente desencorajador](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/transactions-connection-release.html) utilizar a propriedade abaixo, a qual era utilizada em até a versão 2.x. Eu tiraria ela para fazer uns testes.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">on_close</property>
```

Outra propriedade que me parece não se adequada é a hibernate.connection.isolation. É melhor deixar o padrão usado pelo banco de dados. Se adiciona-la tem que saber exatamente que o valor passado significa o que você realmente quer alterar. No seu caso, está usando `TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED`, é isso mesmo que quer?

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">1</property>
```

Uma observação:
A seguinte propriedade é false por padrão, não precisa adiciona-la a não ser que queira passar o valor para true:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda @ramarcio. O isolamento é este mesmo que preciso... pois é uma aplicação para controle de estoque online, então preciso saber as alterações de uma terceira transação antes mesmo da mesma ser comitada...vou fazer o teste tirando o release_mode.

Comment: @ramarcio, ainda continuou com o problema depois das alterações, erro que só acontece depois de parar e depois iniciar a base de dados.

Comment: Que chato, não sei mais o que poderia ser. Por acaso você tentou testar com outro banco de dados, tipo MySQL ou qualquer outro? As vezes pode ser um bug do banco ou do driver de conexão.

Comment: Vou testar sim...e já imaginei isso tbm... muito obrigado pela força.